# load image from storage and display it into listview

Tags: java, android, listview, image-gallery

I am creating an application in which i want to load images from device gallery and display it into the `ListView`.

I need step by step working code example

Comment: Please post some code and see us how far you've gotten and where you're stuck

Comment: "Step by step working code example"? Only if you're paying us ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for getting list of images from gallery -

```
public static ArrayList<String> getImagesFromGallery(Activity activity) {
     Uri uri;
     Cursor cursor;
     int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
     ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
     String absolutePathOfImage = null;
     uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

     String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

     cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
        null, null);

     column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
     column_index_folder_name = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

     listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
    }
     return listOfAllImages;
 }
```

after that you can create a Custom Adapter Class and display all images.

Also remember one more thing to add in manifest file of your app -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope it will help you.